# If condition in mysql not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am having two columns which are of integer types so I want to select the row if one of them have any data except "NULL" or "0".

```
cola     colb    colc    cold
NULL       12     plo     123
12         0      hou     NULL
0          0      plo      0
0          0      hou      123
NULL       13     hou      231
NULL       0      plo      NULL
```

So i want to select only 1,2,5 records 
so basically i have to select if colc is plo then any one of cola or colb should have value and if colc is hou then cold should have value.

I have written a query but its not giving proper result

I am giving my where condition 
where

```
IF ( cold = 'plo', cold, colc) IS NOT NULL 
AND IF ( cold = 'plo', cold, colc) <> '' 
AND ( ( (IF (colc <> 'plo', cola, colc) IS NOT NULL) 
    AND (IF (colc <> 'plo', cola, colc) <> '' )) 
       OR ( (IF (colc <> 'plo', colb, colc) IS NOT NULL) 
          AND (IF (colc <> 'plo', colb, colc) <> '' )) )
```

this is my where condition but after applying this also i am getting results which have both columns as 0 and colc as 'plo'

Is there something wrong in the where clause

Comment: The answers i am getting is not what i want

Comment: The predicates look *way* more complicated than they need to be. The edit to your question makes it more clear what you are trying to achieve. I've added a followup to my previous answer, based on the edit to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The predicates look way more complicated than they need to be.

I'm not sure what the value of `colc` has to do with checking if `cola` or `colb` contains a non-zero integer value.

This would suffice:

```
   WHERE ( t.cola OR t.colb )
```

If you have some condition you want to check on `colc`, where that's not equal to `'plo'` or `'plot'`

```
   WHERE ( t.cola OR t.colb )
     AND t.colc NOT IN ('plo','plot')
```

---

There are other expressions which are more complicated and more ANSI-compliant which will achieve an equivalent result.

***FOLLOWUP***

Assuming the (unfortunately named) columns `cola`, `colb` and `colc` are integer types (or numeric types), you can do something like this:

```
  WHERE (t.colc = 'plo' AND (t.cola OR t.colb))
     OR (t.colc = 'hou' AND t.cold)
```

The question was edited to clarify the specification... query should return rows that meet either of the following conditions:

- if `colc` is 'plo' then any one of `cola` or `colb` should have value other than `0` or `NULL`
- if `colc` is 'hou' then `cold` should have value other than `0` or `NULL`

Let's unpack the WHERE clause a little bit.

We like to use parens around all of the boolean `AND`/`OR` expressions. This makes the order of precedence explicit. This should help the reader who doesn't know/doesn't remember whether `AND` or `OR` has a higher precedence; using parens, even where they aren't strictly necessary, just removes some possible ambiguity, and makes our intent more clear.

In a boolean context, an *integer value* evaluates to either NULL, FALSE, or TRUE

- if the value of the expression is NULL, the boolean evaluation returns NULL.
- if the value of the expression is 0 (zero), it evaluates to boolean FALSE
- if the value of the expression is other than NULL or 0, it evaluates to boolean TRUE

The SQL three-valued boolean logic, expression `(a OR b)` evaluates to TRUE if either `a` or `b` evaluates to TRUE.

```
  OR    TRUE   FALSE  NULL
 -----  -----  -----  -----
 TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE 
 FALSE  TRUE   -      -
 NULL   TRUE   -      -
```

With the `AND` operator, the expression `(a AND b)` evaluates to TRUE only of both `a` and `b` evaluate to TRUE.

***rewrite***

This same WHERE clause:

```
  WHERE (t.colc = 'plo' AND (t.cola OR t.colb))
     OR (t.colc = 'hou' AND t.cold)
```

could be re-written to slightly more verbose:

```
  WHERE (t.colc = 'plo' AND ((t.cola<>0) OR (t.colb<>0)))
     OR (t.colc = 'hou' AND t.cold<>0)
```

or we could re-write that to be more convoluted, but it's not really necessary to do that... it would just make it harder to decipher.

Comment: please do look at it again

Comment: I added followup to my original answer. The predicates are fairly simple, though the usage of integer values evaluated in boolean context may strike MySQL neophytes as a bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

```
NOT(((cola IS NULL) OR (cola=0)) AND ((colb IS NULL) OR (colb=0))) AND colc<>'plo'
```

gets you 2,4 - the bit about colc being plo not being in your definition, but is in the code